# Why does Ctrl-Z on Windows Git bash shell fail?

Tags: cygwin, msysgit, git-bash

I sometimes have to work in Windows, which often means using the Bash shell.  If I am (for example) in `vim` (*not* `gvim`) with several files open, and I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to briefly go back to the shell and do something before returning to `vim`, instead of suspending my `vim` process Git Bash creates a new DOS shell.  This is the last thing I'd ever want.  [Googling turns up nothing useful](https://www.google.com/search?q=Why+does+control+z+on+Windows+Git+bash+shell+fail%3F&sugexp=chrome,mod=7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active) (at this point in time - YMMV in my future).
What is going on?

Comment: In my case it started failiing fairly recently, and I'm not sure why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If I am (for example) in vim (not gvim) with several files open, and I hit ^Z to briefly go back to the shell and do something before returning to vim, instead of suspending my vim process Git Bash creates a new DOS shell.*

If you execute other processes in git bash, CTRL-Z won't suspend them either. Vim works around that and, instead, creates a shell to achieve a similar result. Vim is a tool in windows that doesn't require bash, rather the windows command prompt will be necessarily installed in a windows machine. I assume this is a safe choice of the windows binary program.

*This is the last thing I'd ever want. Googling turns up nothing useful (at this point in time - YMMV in my future). What is going on?*

My guess here is that vim has the CTRL-Z map to creating a DOS shell. If you want to create a bash shell instead, you can type:

`:!sh`

And you will be executing in a bash shell.

Answer (score 1):

My guess that the reason for this is that Windows doesn't implement the POSIX suspend process API. I had the same issue and haven't found a general solution. But for specific common cases (such as gvim), a work around is to create a script somewhere in your PATH (e.g. /c/bin/gvim) along the lines of

```
   #!/bin/env bash
   /c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Vim/vim73/gvim.exe $@ &
```

Comment: If I understand you, you're using this as a wrapper for gvim, and you're implying that ^Z ***WILL*** work for the wrapper script, even though it doesn't work for the actual executable?   Okay, that makes sense, since the real executable is an *exe* file.

Comment: Sorry, no, ^Z still won't work. All the script does is put gvim into background when I type "gvim" in bash, so that I don't have to ^Z to type the next command. Basically, it just saves having to remember to type & after the command.

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps me.  I'm using vim, not gvim, so it's open in the terminal.  I want a way to suspend it to return to the command line.

Comment: Hm I see. In this case, I believe you might be out of luck. The only thing I can suggest is to map "vim" to "start vim", which would run vim in a separate cmd window, freeing bash to receive input. But again, that's not really what you're looking for. Sorry I can't be of more help.