# Freeing Terminal While Using gVim

Tags: vim, vi, git-bash

Is there a way that I can free my terminal from running the gVim process w/o quitting gVim so that I can continue to use the terminal? I'd like to be able to 
do something similar to what I do with emacs. With emacs I can either use the `emacs [file]` command to have the process run through the terminal, or I can use the `runemacs [file]` command to keep the terminal free.

I start gVim with the command:

```
gvim [file]
```

and then the terminal hangs until I `:quit` gVim. When I searched for an answer to this question on the web, people advised that the best thing to do was to use `ctrl-z` to suspend the vim process and then use `fg` to return. However, this fails to work for me in both command line and gVim mode. I'm using Git Bash for my terminal on Windows 7.

Comment: `gvim [file] &`? It should run in background with the `&` as any other proccess

Comment: I'd recommend using vim rather than gvim.  Do you need your terminal for something else _while_ you're editing your file?

Comment: That actually works, although it gives me output `[1] 972`. What exactly does that appended & do?

Comment: @Will I'm usually navigating through directories, using git, maybe running Python interpreter. There's a good chance that I just don't know how to use the terminal effectively, but for whatever reason I use it concurrently with vim at the moment.

Comment: Ah, in that case I would go with @mMontu's answer for now.  Check this out: http://bashitout.com/2013/05/18/Ampersands-on-the-command-line.html  But if you like bash, I would recommend trying out a real Linux distro.  Linux Mint Cinnamon come with a terminal that has tabs for exactly this problem!

Comment: What you want is the default behavior on Linux/BSD/Mac OS X; we even have to use a special flag (`-f`) to *prevent* it. Do you use a cygwin-provided gvim or a Windows GViM?

Comment: @romainl I think it's a Windows gvim. I installed it using the Windows installer.

Comment: My experience is that Windows gvim, when launched from git-bash, does not fork, but it *does* properly fork when launched from `cmd`. I find this a bit mystifying.

Comment: Looks like using `gvim.bat` instead of `gvim` has the right behavior. How this works is still pretty mysterious; `gvim.bat` is inside `C:\Windows` and therefore isn't on the git-bash `$PATH` (at least by default), so `which gvim.bat` and `hash gvim.bat` both fail. But `type gvim.bat` shows `gvim.bat is hashed (/c/windows/gvim.bat)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could run gvim in background as any other process:

```
gvim [file] &
```

After executing this command you receive a message indicating the pid of the new process. When you end it you should receive a similar message on that shell.

---

**Edit:**

The `ctrl-z`/`fg` problem is probably related to windows. [This question states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355591/) that GitBash would create a new shell instead of returning to the current one, so it probably doesn't work as in Linux. A possible solution would be to run your commands from gVim, either calling the shell through `:!` on mappings, or plugins/commands ([fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) for git, `:py` or some plugin for python interpreter, etc).

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks! Do you know why `ctrl-z` and `fg` don't work? Is this an idiosyncratic Windows thing?